# What first run in mysql query

Tags: mysql

Dear friends i am unable to understand mysql query from where.

```
select * from `tablename` where name='123'
```

in this query which section run first select or where.
And in where clause how run mysql from left to right or right to left.

In query

```
"select * from where id='123' and name like 'as%' or name like '% as'"
```

its give result of all id, not only id=123. How its run.

Comment: MySQL is read right to left

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in case when i write a query "select * from where id='123' and name like 'as%' or name like '% as'" its give result of all id, not only id=123 it shows all ids

Comment: In which the question you asked is different from the one you intended to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query says that:

Select all the rows from a particular database which holds a table named as "example table" in it where name is equal to "123"

```
So, this query will fetch all the rows from the table where it encounters name as "123"
```

Note: name in the above query is a column in the table.

Hope this helps

**EDIT**

As OP modified the question explanation goes as:

When in a query if `LIKE` clause is used with `WHERE` clause then the query becomes like:

This

```
"select * from table where id='123' and name like 'as%' or name like '% as'"
```

Will become:

```
"select * from table where id='123' UNION select * from table where name like 'as%' or name like '% as'"
```

This is why you are getting combined results of `where` and `like`

Comment: please check my comments on above

Comment: re the edit: you parsed the query incorrectly :) It does something else.

Comment: would you like to mention the error? @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Sure. The query logic. `a and b or c` is `(a and b) or c`, not `a and (b or c)`.

Comment: you can edit my answer if you like. Thx

Comment: Nope, I'm good.

Comment: logic updated..

Comment: @AmbrishPathak Still your query does something different from the one in the question. You didn't fix the important bit.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to create a result set
It is executed in 3 phases:

```
1. FROM table-name            // Scan all the tuples [rows] in this table
2. WHERE column-name = '123'  // Extract those rows that satisfies some selection criteria, and ignore the rest
3. SELECT *                   // Include ALL the columns in the tuple in the result set [Asterisk is like a wild-card]
```

Answer (score -1):

In Your above Query the select Statement will be Executed first `select * from tablename` and then the condition will be executed `Where` clause and in `Where` clause the execution works from the left to right `where name='123'` the Column `name` compares the value to `name='123'`.